# Resolve the build waring The parameter to the compiler is invalid, '/define:$(BUILDCONFIGURATION)' will be ignored in NET 6.0

Tags: azure-devops, pipeline, .net-6.0

in my pipeline build .yml I  have `buildConfiguration: "Release"` and use it in the build command

```
task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: Build
            inputs:
              command: build
              projects: "**/*.csproj"
              arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)
```

I got

> 6.0.101\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): Warning MSB3052: The parameter to the compiler is invalid, '/define:$(BUILDCONFIGURATION)' will be ignored.

in NET 6.0 build. Any suggestions for fix this warning?

Comment: can you share the whole yaml?

Comment: sorry not permitted to share the complete file , above is the task only I used defined variable in beginning of the pipeline yml file
 variables:
            buildConfiguration: "Release"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I resolved** the above build issue by updating the pipeline[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Resolve the build waring The parameter to the compiler is invalid, '/define:$(BUILDCONFIGURATION)' will be ignored in NET 6.0

Since you could not share the whole YAML file, to resolve this issue requires you to do more troubleshooting.

As a suggestion, you can try changing your variable to a specific value to test if the issue persists, just instead of `$(buildConfiguration)` to `release`:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: Net6Test/Net6Test/Net6Test.csproj
    arguments: '--configuration release'
```

As test, I have created a .NET 6 sample project, and build it with below YAML scripts, and it works fine:

```
pool:
  name: xxxx

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: Net6Test/Net6Test/Net6Test.csproj
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply , I got resolved this warning by updating the azure pipeline as follows